# How do I improve the performance of this groupby and aggregate in PySpark?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to convert a dataframe to a RDD and then perform an aggregation operation (key = (AccountKey, x). Aggregate max for key 1, max for key 2, and max for key 3) on it. But unfortunately, I feel like I still don't understand how to make it happen. I can perform this on a dataframe, but the performance is poor due to shuffling (I tried repartitioning, but it did not help). How do I go about improving from a performance aspect?

Here is my code for performing groupby and aggregate on the dataframe:

```
def operation_xy(df):
    # Groupby Account and x
    groupByExpr = ['Account', 'x']
    exprs = [F.max(F.col(c)) for c in ['1', '2', '3']]

    return df.groupBy(groupByExpr).agg(*exprs)
```

Here is my input:

```
[Row(AccountKey='5878', x=32.0, 1=False, 2=False, 3=False)]
[Row(AccountKey='5178', x=24.0, 1=False, 2=False, 3=True)]
[Row(AccountKey='5178', x=24.0, 1=False, 2=True, 3=False)]
[Row(AccountKey='5178', x=32.0, 1=False, 2=False, 3=False)]
[Row(AccountKey='5878', x=32.0, 1=True, 2=False, 3=True)]
```

Expected output:

```
[Row(AccountKey='5878', x=32.0, 1=True, 2=False, 3=True)]
[Row(AccountKey='5178', x=24.0, 1=False, 2=True, 3=True)]
[Row(AccountKey='5178', x=32.0, 1=False, 2=True, 3=False)]
```

I am a beginner to Spark, so please be gentle :-)

Comment: Your understanding and hope is wrong where RDDs are concerned.

Comment: @thebluephantom So I would go about improving the performance? Is there another way I can approach the problem?

Comment: Hi there, since you are using the combination of ['Account', 'x'] for the groupBy you can try to redistribute the same combination of keys therefore try to repartition by ['Account', 'x'] i.e df.repartition(partition_num, ['Account', 'x'])

Comment: @AlexandrosBiratsis I think I might have figured out what is causing this problem. Before I do the groupby, I perform a join to create the Account column. And when the groupby happens, it seems like the data needs to be partitioned. Would this help with your redistribution suggestion?

Comment: So what columns are being used in the join? Also what is the size of the data?